Why is this A major blues notated in C major?
The sheet music for Charlie Byrd’s Spanish Guitar Blues (produced by Columbia Music Co., © 1961) is in the key of C major, but it seems obvious to me that the piece is in A major.

I understand that it is not always straightforward with jazz but the solo starts and ends in A and the main changes are clear: A, D7, E7. He also uses lots of other chords including Cdim and Cm6, as well as the G in the first line. I know that the key signature would be C major if it was an Am blues but this clearly is not. Adding the Bm could also possibly mean that this could be in D major - since D7, Bm, G, E, A7 is a pretty common set of chords - but the Cdim could not fit that key. Either way C major is surely impossible.
Why might there be a mismatch between the sheet music key and the home key of a piece?

It's not uncommon to notate jazz music without key signature. It doesn't mean to suggest the key of the piece, but rather make it easier to read music which uses modulations and alterations a lot and would require many accidentals anyway.
The key of the piece is of course A major. The reason is that it a follows familiar blues form in A, and the harmonic progression surely will resolve to A in the part of the score not included in your picture. There is however no reason for the chords to stay diatonic in a scale, neither in jazz and blues, neither in classical music.

OK, so this is a stylistic convention when preparing sheet music. I was initially confused by this answer because to my mind the only notation that ignores key signature is TAB which indicates tuning instead, but now I realize that ‘key signature’ is used in two ways so that ‘C key signature’ has in effect the same meaning as ‘no key signature’. I use the first in the question but since there are no sharps and flats on the stave here it is also “without key signature”.

Blues tends to use a different set of notes from the 'standard' scale. There are two blues scales, major and minor. The minor blues scale in key A uses the C pentatonic notes, plus the bluesey ♭5. So it would make sense to write out a Blues in key A with the key signature of no sharps or flats - i.e. C.
It could have been written in the 'proper' key signature of A, with its three sharps, but then just about every C and every G would need to have naturals before them, to get that Blues sound. That would make the piece cumbersome to read, so putting it 'into key C' makes life easier.
But - there is also the major Blues set of notes, which does involve the M3 and M6 of key A, so they would then need to have accidentals attached to them!
Blues pieces often stray between the minor and major Blues sets of notes (not leaving out very many notes from the chromatic scale, as it happens!), but primarily, the key signature of the key a m3 above, as here, is the favoured one. Were it E Blues, the key signature would be one sharp - F♯.
You've also nearly fallen into the trap we see here so often - chords out of key. There's no reason (in fact many good reasons) why chords that don't belong to the immediate key family are used. Someone out there is spreading the rumour that it's naughty to do just that. It just is not!

Yes @Tim I know that the C pentatonic = Am pentatonic and the Aeolian mode of C is the Am scale but I thought I indicated that in the question. Are you saying that sheet music is written to minimize the accidentals in the text? That would make some sense, even if not good sense. I don't think I've fallen into the trap of thinking that chords out of key are not allowed in a piece.

@Tim I think you're being over-ingenious here!  There are probably more accidentals in this version that there would be  with an A major key signature!   He's just decided to not use a key signature.
